# 404 - don't think it's working

Tags: templates, 404

I've created a `/404.group/index.html` that contains my desired 404 page. In `Design ‣ Templates ‣ Global Preferences`, I've set my 404 to `404/index`.

When I go to domain.com/some-crazy-made-up-url, I do not get the 404 page. However, I do see it when I go to domain.com/404.

What am I doing wrong? I have Enable Strict URLs set to "yes".

Comment: Do you get a blank screen or does it render another template? Try enabling Error Reporting and Template Debugging to shed more light. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html

Comment: It renders the homepage template. I'm not sure if I see anything odd in template debugging. Nothing seems out of place.

Comment: do you have strict url's set to no or yes?

Comment: "yes", per my original post.

Comment: If you haven't worked this out, yet, can you revise your question and include the `exp:channel:entries` tag on your home page? Setting  `require_entry="yes"` as a parameter, as well as having `{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}` might be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your htaccess file. It's possible you have a 404 redirect statement there too which should be removed.

Comment: Nothing in htaccess that relates to 404. I checked the server response for the page I expect to return a 404; it is returning a 404 (used Chrome's web developer toolbar to verify).

Comment: Try disabling extensions in index.php to see if one is causing the issue...

Answer (score -1):

Is this not a simple issue with using .html and not .php?
If you create the 404 group page as 404.group/index.php see what you get when you throw in a random url.

Comment: The correct extension for ExpressionEngine templates is .html.